# NSTextField in SwiftUI using NSViewRepresentable loses constraints when inside ScrollView

Tags: swift, swiftui, appkit

I'm trying to recreate SwiftUI's `Text` View, but with `NSTextField`, because the low resolution text rendering of SwiftUI is making my app look pixelated. AppKit's NSTextField on the other hand renders at a crisper resolution, but the constraints behavior is weird.

Here is an example of the NSTextField label in a VStack:

[image: VStack without ScrollView]

I have purposely put the label into a subview to more closely represent how it'll be used in the actual app, and so that the labels are not direct children of the ScrollView, but even still, once I wrap a `ScrollView` around the `VStack`, my `NSTextField` labels lose all line wrapping.

[image: VStack with ScrollView]

I have found a way to get around this by using a `GeometryReader`, and passing an explicit NSSize to the label to bound its width, but because I'm trying to replace `Text`, a View that my app utilizes hundreds of, `GeometryReader` seems to cause some hangs when many re-renders are caused. Is there anyway to accomplish this line wrapping by using NSTextField inside a SwiftUI view with NSViewRepresentable, without having to use `GeometryReader` or manually control the width? I just want the text to fill with width of the parent view, and wrap if it's longer than can fit on one line.

Here is the `NSTextField` code:

```
struct MyLabel: NSViewRepresentable {
    var string: String

  init(_ string: String) {
    self.string = string
  }

  func makeNSView(context _: Context) -> NSTextField {
    let tf = NSTextField(frame: .zero)
    tf.stringValue = string
    tf.isBordered = false
    tf.drawsBackground = false
    tf.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    tf.isBezeled = false
    tf.isEditable = false
    tf.isSelectable = false
    tf.maximumNumberOfLines = 0
    tf.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
    tf.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
    tf.font = NSFont.titleBarFont(ofSize: 18)
    tf.textColor = .white
    return tf
  }

  func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSTextField, context _: Context) {
  }
}
```

And here is the SwiftUI view code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  struct SomeOtherView: View {
    let string: String
    init(_ string: String) {
      self.string = string
    }

    var body: some View {
      VStack(spacing: 0) {
        MyLabel(string)
      }
    }
  }
  var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.vertical) {
      VStack(spacing: 0) {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
          SomeOtherView("This is a test to see if things work.")
          SomeOtherView("This is a test to see if things work.")
          SomeOtherView("This is a test to see if things work.")
          SomeOtherView("This is a test to see if things work.")
        }
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
          SomeOtherView("This is a test to see if things work.")
          SomeOtherView("This is a test to see if things work.")
          SomeOtherView("This is a test to see if things work.")
          SomeOtherView("This is a test to see if things work.")
        }
      }
      .frame(width: 200).frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
      .border(.red)
    }.border(.blue)
  }
}
```